# Why is length defined as a variable instead of using queue.length in the for loop?

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

I am making my way through Code School's JavaScript Road Trip courses, and this lesson is the first one that is really giving me a hard time. This is the solution they provided for part 3 - level 1 - challenge 13.

```js
var puzzlers = [
  function(a) { return 8 * a - 10; },
  function(a) { return (a - 3) * (a - 3) * (a - 3); },
  function(a) { return a * a + 4; },
  function(a) { return a % 5; }
];
var start = 2;

var applyAndEmpty = function(input, queue) {
  var length = queue.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    input = queue.shift()(input);
  }
  return input;
};

alert(applyAndEmpty(start, puzzlers));
```

I don't understand why they create a variable called `length`. Initially, I would have thought to simply use `i < queue.length` in the `for` loop. So, why is it declared as a variable before the `for` loop?

Additionally, I am really confused by what is happening in the `for` loop.

For reference, this was my code before I got the answer from codeschool:

```js
var puzzlers = [
  function(a) { return 8 * a - 10; },
  function(a) { return (a - 3) * (a - 3) * (a - 3); },
  function(a) { return a * a + 4; },
  function(a) { return a % 5; }
];
var start = 2;

var applyAndEmpty = function(input, queue){
  for (var i=0; i<queue.length; i++){
    queue.shift(input);
  };
}

alert(applyAndEmpty(start, puzzlers));
```

First time posting, so please forgive me if I'm doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So why is it declared as a variable before the for loop?

<strike>For not reading the `length` property in each iteration. It makes sense to cache the `length` property for huge arrays, but here it's somehow a premature-optimization. One can also cache the variable in the `for` loop:</strike>

```
for (var i = 0, length = queue.length; i < length; i++) {
   input = queue.shift()(input);
}
```

Well, the above paragraph is not correct in this case. Since the the for loop executes the second expression in each iteration, without caching the `length` property the loop doesn't work properly as the loop body modifies the length of the array by calling the `shift` method.

The code simply passes the input to each function in the array sequentially. The returned value of each function is passed to the next function. It works like the `Array.prototype.reduce` function. Knowing how the [`Array.prototype.shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) function and the invocation operator ([`()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)) works will help you to better understand the code.

```
// remove the first element from the array and return it
let functionReference = queue.shift();
// call the function by using `()` operator and update the input
input = functionReference(input);
```

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift

Shift does remove the first element of an array and returns it. If you would use queue.length the for loop would not iterate through the whole array as the array size decreases with each loop (by 1). Creating a variable with the initial size of the array solves that (in this case length).

Comment: So by declaring queue.length as a variable, this retains the length as the original length of the array? (4 in this case)

Versus what I did in my code, causing the length to count down, therefore never getting to the last function?

Comment: this is correct. if we take your example with 4 iterations, the loop would only execute 2 iterations if the length variable would not exist.